# Spring : Scope 'request' is not active for the current thread?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

How to share the request context with another thread (method called using async) in spring boot? I know there exists RequestContextListener and ContextLoaderListener but haven't seen any examples using Java Config.

Comment: This might be useful http://stackoverflow.com/a/33337838/892788