# RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes() getting null after @Async

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, asynchronous

We are using @Async for multithreading. Untill each multithreading method i can see values for RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes().

But when i debug inside the method i'm getting request attributes as NULL.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Provide some code, please.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to enable request scope in async task executor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23732089/how-to-enable-request-scope-in-async-task-executor)

Comment: related link, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23732089/how-to-enable-request-scope-in-async-task-executor

Answer (score 2):

To get around this issue we created a `ContextAwareRunnable` Object that was pre-populated with the current requestHolder, securityContextHolder, etc, so that all spawned threads would be able to execute as if it were running in the main thread.

Comment: Dan, can you please elaborate a bit more about that? Also, may i know why once Async method starts RequestAttributes are vanishing (Is that because of newly created thread)? Thanks!

Comment: @universe - Yes, the new thread has not been populated with any of the request details from the main thread.

Comment: If you need those details, I'd run the method calls from an ExecutorService instead of marking the methods @Async.

Comment: Thanks. But, i don't think i can change method calls (That will be a major change). Anyway can we set those request details to all spawned threads before @Async?

Comment: Why can't you change up how your method is being called.  It's as simple as a single line of code  `executor.submit(() -> YourClass.methodName(), contextAwareExecutor);`

Comment: We are not using executor.submit. We implemented async framework using Spring Annotations. 
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-async

Comment: Goodluck with it

Comment: Thank you @Dan. universe you want to check out this link for implementation, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23732089/how-to-enable-request-scope-in-async-task-executor

Answer (score 2):

By default `ThreadLocal` variable is used as holder for request attributes. That means that only single thread which handles entire https request is able to access request attributes. In contrast `@Async` methods are processed by threads from a separate thread pool so they can't access the attributes.

However there is one more `InheritableThreadLocal` variable which could be used as request attributes holder instead for default one. You can enabled it by setting `threadContextInheritable` property to `true` in `DispatcherServlet` or `RequestContextFilter`.

Take a look at implementation of [`RequestContextHolder`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-web/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/context/request/RequestContextHolder.java) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

`RequestContextHolder` is request-bound (which means thread-bound in this case). I've fixed the issue with nullability using this kind of wrapper:

```java
  private Executor wrap(Executor executor) {
    return task -> executor.execute(wrap(task));
  }

  private Runnable wrap(Runnable task) {
    RequestAttributes requestAttributes = RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes();
    return () -> {
      try {
        RequestContextHolder.setRequestAttributes(requestAttributes);
        task.run();
      } finally {
        RequestContextHolder.resetRequestAttributes();
      }
    };
  }
```