# Spring Async, How to enable request scope in async task executor

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, spring-boot, asynchronous

I try to use `@Async` de spring, And in my service I use a bean with scope `session`, always I got the bellow error:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'scopedTarget.classSession':
>   Scope 'session' is not active for the current thread; consider
>   defining a scoped proxy for this bean if you intend to refer to it
>   from a singleton; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException:
>   No session found and request already completed - cannot create new
>   session!

As is mentioned, No session found and request already completed. I implemented AsyncConfigurer in order to overide the ThreadPoolTaskExecutor: bellow my code

Controller:

```
@Autowired 
MyService myService;

@RequestMapping(value = "/doIt", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
public HttpEntity initiateCurrent(..){

myService.do();
...
}
```

MyService

```
@Autowired 
ClassWithScopeSession classSession;

@Async("taskExecutor")
public void do(){
....
...
classSession.doService();
}
```

//Overide the ThreadPoolTaskExecutor

```
public class ContextAwareCallable<T> implements Callable<T> {
    private Callable<T> task;
    private RequestAttributes context;

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext appContext;

    public ContextAwareCallable(Callable<T> task, RequestAttributes context) {
        this.task = task;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public T call() throws Exception {
        if (context != null) {
            RequestContextHolder.setRequestAttributes(context);
        }
        try {
            return task.call();
        } finally {
            RequestContextHolder.resetRequestAttributes();
        }
    }
}

public class ContextAwarePoolExecutor extends ThreadPoolTaskExecutor {
    @Override
    public <T> Future<T> submit(Callable<T> task) {
        return super.submit(new ContextAwareCallable(task, RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes()));
    }

    @Override
    public <T> ListenableFuture<T> submitListenable(Callable<T> task) {
        return super.submitListenable(new ContextAwareCallable(task, RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes()));
    }
}

@Configuration
@EnableAsync
public class ExecutorConfig  implements AsyncConfigurer {

    @Override
    @Bean(name="taskExecutor")
    public Executor getAsyncExecutor() {
        return new ContextAwarePoolExecutor();
    }

    @Override
    public AsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler getAsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

I followed this [response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23732089/how-to-enable-request-scope-in-async-task-executor/33337838#33337838)

Comment: Not sure it will help, but instead of autowiring `classSession`, try passing `classSession` as a parameter to `do()`.

Comment: @AndrewS Thank you for your suggestion, but no it's not possible...

Answer (score 3):

You need to override execute method instead:

```
@Override
public void execute(Runnable task) {
    super.execute(new ContextAwareCallable(task, RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes()));
}
```

And update your ContextAwareCallable to:

```
public class ContextAwareCallable implements Runnable {

    private Runnable task;
    private RequestAttributes context;

    public ContextAwareCallable(Runnable task, RequestAttributes context) {
        this.task = task;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        if (context != null) {
            RequestContextHolder.setRequestAttributes(context);
        }

        task.run();
    }
}
```

I am not a guru, but this solution worked for me.

Once you annotate a method with `@Async`, it runs `execute()` method on `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor` class, not `submit()` or `submitListenable()`.

On my solution it returns `CompletableFuture`. It's strange, because execute does not return anything.

Hope it will help someone.

Answer (score 0):

I have a multiTenant app with async methods. Someone returns a CompletableFuture.
As said before, now it works for me!

```
@Configuration
```

@EnableAsync
public class DashBoardAsyncExecutorConfig {

```
@Bean("MyTaskExecutor")
public TaskExecutor taskExecutor() {
    ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ContextAwarePoolExecutor();
    executor.setCorePoolSize(5);
    executor.setMaxPoolSize(5);
    executor.setQueueCapacity(500);
    executor.setAllowCoreThreadTimeOut(true);
    executor.setThreadNamePrefix("thread");
    executor.initialize();
    return executor;
}
```

}

public class ContextAwarePoolExecutor extends ThreadPoolTaskExecutor {

```
   @Override
   public <T> Future<T> submit(Callable<T> task) {
      return super.submit(new ContextAwareCallable(task, RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes()));
   }

   @Override
   public <T> ListenableFuture<T> submitListenable(Callable<T> task) {
     return super.submitListenable(new ContextAwareCallable(task, 
     RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes()));

   }
   
   //FOR COMPLETABLE FUTURE
   @Override
   public void execute(Runnable task) {
       super.execute(new ContextAwareCallableRunnable(task, RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes()));
   }
```

}

```
public class ContextAwareCallableRunnable<T> implements Runnable {
private Runnable task;
private RequestAttributes context;

public ContextAwareCallableRunnable(Runnable task, RequestAttributes context) {
    this.task = task;
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    if (context != null) {
        RequestContextHolder.setRequestAttributes(context);
    }
    task.run();
}
```

}