# How can I use ApplicationContext session scoped classes from a different thread

Tags: java, spring-boot, threadpool

Using @Async annotation I want to call a method in a different thread that has access to Session and Request scoped classes.

However when the ApplicationContext tries to get the bean the following exception is generated:

`Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'scopedTarget.sessionInfoClass': Scope 'session' is not active for the current thread;`

I had tried extending ApplicationContextAware class to hold the main thread context.

Also I had tried the suggested solution from this question [How to enable request scope in async task executor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23732089/how-to-enable-request-scope-in-async-task-executor/33337838#33337838)

Source coude is in Github

https://github.com/saavedrah/spring-threadSample

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created a pull request for your repo that solves the issue.

Basically, I extended [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23732089/how-to-enable-request-scope-in-async-task-executor/33337838#33337838) also for `Runnable` case.

To verify it, run the `ThreadSampleApplication` class then hit http://localhost:8080/testAsync

Comment: Thank you Eugen, I checked using the Url and it worked, I will mark this as answered. Additionally do you know how to fix the RunnableServiceTest ?

Comment: You need to use an `WebClient` to hit the same URL. For a very straightforward example see https://dzone.com/articles/spring-boot-webclient-and-its-testing