# Method Annotated with @Async with a Rest Template call in a Springboot application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, asynchronous, resttemplate

I have a problem with @Async and Rest Template call; here is my Main Application class, with a task executor Bean and EnableAsync Annotation

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan({"org.***"})
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
@EnableAsync
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude={DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class,HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class})
@EnableFeignClients(basePackages = {"org.service.feign"})
public class MainApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    /**
     * <p>main.</p>
     *
     * @param args an array of {@link java.lang.String} objects.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MainApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean(name = "threadPoolTaskExecutor")
      public Executor taskExecutor() {
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        executor.setCorePoolSize(5);
        executor.setMaxPoolSize(5);
        executor.setQueueCapacity(100);
        executor.setThreadNamePrefix(“CustomLookup-");
        executor.initialize();
        return executor;
      }
    /**
     * Configure.
     *
     * @param application the application
     * @return the spring application builder
     */
    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(MainApplication.class);
    }
    
    /**
     * <p>requestContextListener.</p>
     *
     * @return a {@link org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener} object.
     */
    @Bean
    public RequestContextListener requestContextListener() {
        return new RequestContextListener();
   }
}
```

this is my my test service with Async annotation that I call in a Rest Controller:

```
@Service
public class TestService {

   

    @Async("threadPoolTaskExecutor")
    public ResponseEntity<Object> test()
            throws Exception{
        PagedRequest<SearchRequest> request = new PagedRequest<SearchRequest>();

        SearchRequest filters = new Request();

        filters.setCod(“abcdeg");

        request.setFilters(filters);
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        restTemplate.setInterceptors(Collections.singletonList(new RestInterceptor()));  // here I set a custom headers
        final HttpHeaders theJsonHeader = new HttpHeaders();
        theJsonHeader.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
        final MultiValueMap<String, Object> theMultipartRequest = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        String someJsonString = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(request);
        theMultipartRequest.add("request", new HttpEntity<>(someJsonString, theJsonHeader));
        ResponseEntity<Object> response = null;
        final HttpEntity<PagedRequest<SearchRequest>> theHttpEntity = new HttpEntity<>(request, theJsonHeader);

        String path = “http://...”; //url removed for privacy

        response = restTemplate.postForEntity(path, theHttpEntity, Object.class);
        return response;
        
    }

}
```

This service return a nullPointer on the rest template; this is the stacktrace

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.hasError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:61) ~[spring-web-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.handleResponse(RestTemplate.java:773) ~[spring-web-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:743) ~[spring-web-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:677) ~[spring-web-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.postForEntity(RestTemplate.java:452) ~[spring-web-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.REL
```

Here the code of my RestIntercept that i add in my RestTemplate

```
public class RestInterceptor implements ClientHttpRequestInterceptor {

   
    @Override
    public ClientHttpResponse intercept(HttpRequest request, byte[] body, ClientHttpRequestExecution execution) throws IOException {
        
        ServletRequestAttributes requestAttributes = (ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes();
        if (requestAttributes == null)
            return null;
        
        HttpServletRequest req = requestAttributes.getRequest();
        if (req == null || req.getHeader(PrevConstants.USER_KEY)==null || req.getHeader(PrevConstants.JWT_HEADER_NAME)==null)
            return null;


        String userKey = req.getHeader(PrevConstants.USER_KEY);

        String jwt = req.getHeader(PrevConstants.JWT_HEADER_NAME);
        
        if (jwt == null) {
            jwt = "custom jwt";
        }
       
        else if ( !jwt.startsWith("Bearer")) {                     jwt = "Bearer " + jwt;                 }

        request.getHeaders().set(PrevConstants.USER_KEY, userKey);
        request.getHeaders().set(PrevConstants.JWT_HEADER_NAME, jwt);         
        
        ClientHttpResponse response = execution.execute(request, body);
        return response;
    }
}
```

but if i remove, @EnableAsync and @Async the simple Rest Template works perfectly.

When i pass the HttpServlet request, the Eclipse Debug show this:

[image]
What's the problem? I don't know.
Thank you for the responses

Comment: The NPE is occurring because the response is `null`. That shouldn’t happen. Can you share the code for `RestInterceptor`? It could be involved in that.

Comment: @AndyWilkinson i have edited my answer with the code of RestInterceptor

Comment: check out this -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23732089/how-to-enable-request-scope-in-async-task-executor

Answer (score 2):

`RequestContextHolder` holds the context for the request being handled by the current thread. When you use `@Async` your interceptor is called on a different thread to the one that is handling the request. As a result, `RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes()` returns `null` and your interceptor then returns a `null` response. To comply with the contract of `ClientHttpRequestInterceptor#intercept` it has to return a non-null value so this `null` response causes a failure.

If you want to use `@Async`, you'll have to retrieve the `RequestAttributes` in your REST Controller and then pass them into your `TestService` as a parameter to the `test` method. You could then create your `RestInterceptor` with the attributes, rather than it using `RequestContextHolder` to access them:

```
@Async("threadPoolTaskExecutor")
public ResponseEntity<Object> test(RequestAttributes requestAttributes) throws Exception {
    // …
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    restTemplate.setInterceptors(Collections.singletonList(new RestInterceptor(requestAttributes)));
    // …
}
```